# SharedBuffer between Java and C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, macos, java-native-interface, buffer

what I am working on is to read image data from camera using C++ and use JNI to let Java read those image data, and I am using Mac OSX.

The blocker I currently have is, I have not found any method to create a shared memory between two language on Mac OSX.

I could imagine I will be using some buffer to do so, could anyone gives some hints and knowledge towards this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect-int-) to create native accessible memory:

```
public static native void getCameraData(ByteBuffer bb);
```

...

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
getCameraData(bb);
// use data
```

Then on the C++ side, use [`GetDirectBufferAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress), to access the block of memory:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_getCameraData(JNIEnv *env, jclass, jobject bb) {
    void* data = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! There is a question I want to ask.. Does the buffer works like a First In First Out strategy so that the processed image could be deleted so that new image could be put into the buffer?

Comment: @Hong If you're talking about the endian-ness, you can set that with [`order`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-). Otherwise, it's just a block of memory. I'd suggest you read the documentation to get a good idea.

Comment: @Hong No - it's just a lump of memory that Java promises not to move when/if garbage collection occurs.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee  I am continually writing new images to the Buffer, the memory required is quite big. So I am wondering if I could clean the processed image from Java side or C++ side so that more images could be put into the buffer.

Comment: @Hong You could just start writing from the beginning of the block of memory again, that would overwrite any old data that is there.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee Thanks!