# Move C++ memory without copy

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, move

Currently I am working on transfer image from C++ to Java.

The destination location is allocate by Java,

the source location is the image generated by C++, so.

I have a

```
uint8_t* pixelPtr
```

, I want to move the content of this to a

```
__uint8_t* data
```

without copy.

I have 1920*1080*3 bytes in total, so I want to move rather than copy to be fast in computation, I am wondering is there any trick way to do so?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `data = pixelPtr`; `pixelPtr = 0` , or what are we missing ?

Comment: Why the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: What is `__uint8_t` here? Why do you need to move _or_ copy the data? Just make the two pointers point to the same data?

Comment: @nos: Wrong way around?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The memory is allocate by Java and passed from JNI.

Comment: @Hong: So? This question doesn't even mention Java. If you think the Java aspect imposes a constraint on possible solutions, you should say so and explain why.

Comment: If and only if `uint8_t` and `__uint8_t` types are binary equal you can do `data = (uint8_t*)pixelPtr;`

Comment: Okay that's _much_ clearer now thank you

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I have expanded the question.

Comment: I have no idea what your conception of a "move" from one location to another is that affords any possibility of avoiding copying the data.  Copying is the more fundamental concept.  Generally, "moving" means that *after copying* you free / clear / delete the original.

Comment: I also answered [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246338/sharedbuffer-between-java-and-c-using-jni) yesterday. If this is still the same project, instead of creating the `ByteBuffer` on the Java side, you could use the JNI function [`NewDirectByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewDirectByteBuffer) to wrap the block of C++ memory in a `ByteBuffer`, and then `return` it to Java.

Answer (score 2):

Let's recap:

- The source is a buffer allocated in C++ by an image generation function.
- The destination is a buffer allocated in Java by some other code somewhere.
- You want to transfer data between the two buffers.

As long as those two buffers are distinct, there is no "trick" to avoid this. "Moving" in this context would mean swapping the pointers around, but that does nothing to the underlying buffers. You will just have to copy the data.

Explore solutions such as generating the data in the destination buffer in the first place, or making use of appropriate functionality exposed by the C++ image generation function (or the Java code). Unfortunately we can't speculate on the possible existence or form of such solutions, from here.

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, I am new to C++ and I read something called ”move semantics“ to allocate a new object without copy. Is it impossible to imply that technology to this situation?

Comment: @Hong: As I said, no. Move semantics do not "allocate" any "new object"; they merely swap pointers around, in encapsulating types that understand how to handle that, so as to avoid copies. But that won't help you here.

Comment: @Hong think of it as 2 glasses one with water and another empty. Do you know any way to melt those two glasses into one without removing the water? To solve your problem you need to have only one glass before you even put water inside it.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Thank you for your share. I am using external library, so I do not think it is easy to load the content directly into my own buffer, however I found it extreme fast to use memcpy and the overheads is less than 1ms, I guess it does not matter. Thanks!

Comment: @Logman You are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is, you should modify your C++ code so it creates the data not wherever it wants, but in the given place. That is, if you have code like this

```
uint8_t* GenerateImage(...parameters...)
{
    uint8_t* output = ... allocate ...
    return output;
}
```

you should change it to receive the destination as a parameter

```
void GenerateImage(...parameters..., __uint8_t* destination)
{
    ... fill the destination ...
}
```

The latter is better C++ design anyway - this way you don't need to make a separate `DestroyImage` function - the memory is managed entirely by Java.